# Ошибка в JavaScript (Uncaught Error)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /o-kolledzhe
at Function.fa.error (jquery.min.js:2)
at fa.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
at fa.select (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.fa (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.a.find (jquery-migrate.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.a.fn.find (jquery-migrate.min.js:2)
at a.fn.init.n.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
at a.fn.init (jquery-migrate.min.js:2)
at n (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Что делать с данной ошибкой ?

```
<div class="fullwidth">
   <nav class="navbar">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar nav-collapse collapse" style="display:none">
      <ul class="nav menu nav-pills navbar-nav">


        <li><a href="http://ntgmk.ru">Главная</a></li>
       <li class ="dropdown">
          <a id="about" data-target="/o-kolledzhe" class="dropdown-toggle" data-
    toggle="dropdown">О колледже
          <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
           <ul  class="dropdown-menu" style="">          
           <li><a href="/o-kolledzhe/obshchie-svedeniya">Общие сведения</a></li>
           <li><a href="/o-kolledzhe/novosti">Новости</a></li>
           <li><a href="/o-kolledzhe/rukovodstvo">Руководство</a></li>
           <li><a href="/o-kolledzhe/prep">Педагогический состав</a></li>
           <li><a href="/o-kolledzhe/filial">Филиал</a></li>
           <li><a href="/o-kolledzhe/resursnyj-tsentr">Ресурсный центр 
    профориентации</a></li>
           <li><a href="/o-kolledzhe/mfc">Многофункциональный центр прикладных 
    квалификаций</a></li>
           <li><a href="http://museum.ntgmk.ru/" target="_blanck">Музейный 
    комплекс</a></li>
           <li><a href="/o-kolledzhe/anti-corruption">Противодействие 
    коррупции</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

       <li class="dropdown">
         <a id="drop1" data-target="/cvedeniya-ob-obrazovatelnoj-organizatsii" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Сведения об образовательной организации            
           <span class="caret"></span>
         </a> 
          <ul  class="dropdown-menu" style="">

            <li><a href="/sveden/common">Основные сведения</a></li>
            <li><a href="/sveden/struct">Структура и органы управления образовательной организацией</a></li>  
            <li><a href="/sveden/document">Документы</a></li> 
            <li><a href="/sveden/education">Образование</a></li>
            <li><a href="/sveden/eduStandarts">Образовательные стандарты</a></li>
            <li><a href="/sveden/employees">Руководство. Педагогический (научно-педагогический) состав</a></li>
            <li><a href="/sveden/objects">Материально-техническое обеспечение и оснащённость образовательного процесса</a></li>
            <li><a href="/sveden/paid-edu">Платные образовательные услуги</a></li>
            <li><a href="/sveden/grants">Стипендии и иные виды материальной поддержки</a></li>
            <li><a href="/sveden/budget">Финансово-хозяйственная деятельность</a></li>
            <li><a href="/sveden/vacant">Вакантные места для приема (перевода)</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li> 
        <li><a href="/kontakty">Контакты</a></li> 
        <li><a href="http://sdo.ntgmk.ru/moodle/" target="_blanck">Система дистанционного обучения</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('&template=accessibility'); ?>">
<img align=right src="images/blind.png" alt="" width="184" height="45" /></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Для начала покажите код, где срабатывает эта ошибка

Comment: все стандартно : ищем причину возникновения - исправляем.

Comment: Syntax error - указывает на то, что это синтаксическая ошибка в вашем коде. Это может быть что угодно, например puction вместо function. Покажите свой код.

Comment: с кодом все могут, а вы попробуйте без кода) непонятна суть вопроса

Comment: Как найти файл, в котором содержится этот код ?

То, что я написал ранее, содержится в инспекторе. Но в файле "jquery.min.js" я не нашел "/o-kolledzhe"

Comment: вам надо не в `jquery.min.js` искать а в вашем коде, ибо выглядит ето так будто в своем коде вы сделали что-то не так, и jquery валится изза етого

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych то есть ошибка может быть даже и не в скрипте ?

Comment: наверное у вас joomla, попробуйте обновить до последней версии jquery-migrate.min.js или отключить JMigrate в общем, покопайте в ту сторону

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что в коде написано: data-target="/o-kolledzhe"
Это решало проблему того, что кнопки меню пропадали при нажатии: style="display:none"

Но, как теперь сделать так, чтобы кнопки не меняли стиль и в то же время не было ошибок ?